# Using Django's "update_or_create" function, returns nothing for me

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform, formset

So, I'm working with Django Model Formsets.

First, I'm grabbing stuff from my API using Django RestFramework:

```
    itemsQuery = People.objects.using('api').prefetch_related('staff').filter(id__in=['293992'])

    ### I can dump itemsQuery and get a bunch of data that I need
    ### Ie: logger.error(itemsQuery.values()), so I know stuff is in there
```

Then, I try to populate my local db with the data from my API like so:

```
       for people in itemsQuery:
        allPeople = NewPeople.objects.update_or_create(
             name=people.staff.name,
        )

        ### I can dump the data out like so:
        ### logger.error(people.staff.name)
        ### and get a bunch of names, so I know that part is at least working
        ### and "name" is a field in my model

        something = NewPeople.objects.filter(section_id__in=['293992'])

       formset = PeopleFormSet(queryset=something)

       context['formset'] = formset

       return context
```

Here is my template:

```
 {% for form in formset %} 
      <div>first_name: {{ form.name.value }}</div>          
 {% endfor %}
```

But nothing outputs. Empty.

Am I using the update_or_create incorrectly? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You've created the NewPeople objects just with `name`; you haven't set any other attributes. But when you get the `something` queryset, you query by `section_id`. You never set any section ids; so that query will always be empty.

Comment: I figured it out! my db was all messed up so clearing it and runnign again worked! thanks though for responding!